# TButton does not identify the procedure written by hand delphi fmx

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey

I have a `TButton` on my Form, and I have a procedure that when clicking on this button executes a `ShowMessage()`. Simple. The problem is that I 'erased' this procedure completely and then rewrote it perfectly as it was. The problem is that the button doesn't work anymore, nothing happens. If by chance I click 2x, it will direct a procedure written manually by me and then it works. I would like to know why?

(NOTE: I pasted in the 360 ​​code ​​procedures for 360 buttons in another Delphi FMX project and I would not like to click on 360 buttons just for it to identify a procedure)

Thanks.

Comment: After rewriting the procedure(s), did you remember to re-link them up the button `OnClick` event(s)? Why do you have so many buttons? That is not good on UI resources, let alone good for UI design. And having that many separate procedures is not good for code design/maintenance, either. Do all of the procedures do the same thing for different buttons? Can't you use fewer procedures (ie, 1) that utilize the `Sender` parameter to detect which button is being clicked?

Comment: The huge amount of buttons exist because they are part of a system for selling tokens for clubs where I have buttons for - and + cd product = tag button. Where there are no registered products, they are Visible = False.
All of the - buttons do the same thing, and the + buttons do the same thing too. They call a procedure that performs the action of triggering one or subtracting 1 item from the total sale.
I was looking for some method to automate this 'rereading of buttons and their procedures' automatically. Apparently it doesn't exist.

Comment: I know it's lack of study on my part, but how could I use the Sender of the pressed button and use its Text, Tag and other parameters in a function? Delphi FMX 10.4, my application is Android.

Comment: In this case, the `Sender` points to the `TButton` that is being clicked. So simply type-cast the `Sender` to `TButton` and then use its properties as needed, eg: `procedure TMyForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject); begin ShowMessage(TButton(Sender).Text); end;` And then you can assign that one procedure to the `OnClick` event of all your buttons.

Comment: Sounds like a good example for working with ``TFrame`` to me!

Answer (score 2):

Like Remy Lebeau said! Go to the events tab on the button, double click the onclick event, see if it will direct you to the procedure you have created! If it directs you to the procedure, but nothing happens, try to delete the procedure and everything related to it, then double click the onclick event and write the code again!

Answer (score 0):

You must change  **dfm** file of  your form for declaration of **OnClick = Button1Click;**
One way is :
Right click on form and select 'View as text' and add to base of form structure

```
object Form88: TForm88
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form88'
     ...
     ...

  TextHeight = 15
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 248
    ...
    ....
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Also, you can change dfm file by Editors and use **find and replace** for affect many change on the form suddenly.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you.